# Is there a way to avoid reloading vs code window for changes to python modules to be reflected in other files?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Say I have a Python module with an **init** file like this:

```
# pages/__init__.py
from ..utils.page import Page
from .main_page import MainPage
from typing import Dict, Type

PAGE_MAP: Dict[str, Type[Page]] = {
}

__all__ = ['PAGE_MAP']
```

In the same module I have another file called main_page.py, which holds a Page class that will be put into the PAGE_MAP later.
In my main file, I have want to use this PAGE_MAP, like this:

```
# main.py
from src.pages import PAGE_MAP

def main():
    current_page = 'MainPage'
    PAGE_MAP[current_page]().write()
```

Now, obviously I will have squiggles under the PAGE_MAP call, since the PAGE_MAP is empty, so I cannot access current_page, instantiate the class and call the write method.
Now I update the PAGE_MAPE to contain the 'MainPage':

```
# Update to pages/__init__.py
PAGE_MAP: Dict[str, Type[Page]] = {
    "MainPage": MainPage
}
```

Going back to the main file, why does the squiggles not disappear automatically in vs code? I have to reload the window before the squiggles disappear, or wait an absurd amount of time before it updates. Since it does in fact update after a long time, is there a way to make it update on save, or shorten the time between updates? Or maybe other ways to handle this issue?

I tried searching online, but I can't seem to find other similar problems or possible solutions.

EDIT: as JarroVGIT pointed out, I failed to mention my os. I am using WSL2 Ubuntu on my Windows 11 system. There are other similar issues with WSL in vs code, for example the source control and file explorer needs manual reload by pressing the reload buttons. My issue is likely WSL related, but if anyone has a fix, i'm all ears.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue, are you on Windows/Mac/Linux? One thing that comes to mind is that you can save your files when you leave the focus on that file, that might trigger the Python extension to reload?

Comment: @JarroVGIT Right, it might be a WSL issue, now that you mention it. That would make more sense, since there are some similar issues with the file explorer or source control not updating in vs code as well. So i'm on windows, but using vs code in WSL Ubuntu. I updated the tags, maybe some Ubuntu wizard knows how to fix it.